# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:

Tags: java, android, date

I'm trying to get Date from String,

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

My date string is:

```
Wed, 02 September 2015 08:27:00 MSK
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 02 September 2015 08:27:00 MSK" (at offset 32)
```

What's wrong?
Thx for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you have MSK time. Is your locale English or Russian ? Because if your locale is Russian, September is not a valid month. So, you have 2 options :

1. Change your locale to English.
2. Let your locale in Russian, but write the month in Russian.

Fix for changing the locale to English :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the correct locale. Here you have `Wed, 02 September 2015 08:27:00 MSK` as Date String which include `MSK` which is `TimeZone` of Russia, Moscow. so you need to set `TimeZone` for it

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MCK"));
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
```